# conjugacy in symmetric group

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

I was reading Dummit and Foote and encountered the following statement: any two elements in $S_n$ are conjugate if and only if they have the same cycle types.

However, I am able to produce a counter example:

Let $(1 2 3)$ and $(4 5 6) (7 8)$ be in $S_{10}$, then $(4 5 6) (7 8) =(1 3 2) (4 5 6) (7 8) (1 2 3)$, which show that these two are conjugate.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Your identity just showed that $(456)(78)$ is conjugate to itself.

Comment: Replace $(123)$ and $(321)$ with the identity element instead to see clearly that every element is a conjugate of itself.

Comment: Oh right I was not understanding the definition properly

Answer (score 1):

You have conjugated $(456)(78)$ *by* $(123)$, not shown that they are conjugate *with* each other.

For example, the conjugate of $(456)(78)$ *by* $(45)$ is

$$(45)(456)(78)(45)^{-1}=(546)(78),$$

meaning that $(456)(78)$ and $(546)(78)$ are conjugate *with* each other.

Comment: He _has_ shown that $(456)(78)$ is conjugate with itself.

Comment: Well, yes, @ChrisCuster, but I think that's a happy accident; by "the two", I believe CuriousAlpaca meant $(123)$ and $(456)(78)$.

Comment: I don't know why the OP would think that.  The _accident_ will always occur when you conjugate by a disjoint permutation of course.

Comment: Does this answer you question, @CuriousAlpaca?

Answer (score 0):

Of course a permutation is conjugate to itself.  It has the same cycle type as itself, as well.  You could just as well have conjugated by the identity.

---

Conjugation takes $k$-cycles to $k$-cycles:  $\pi^{-1}(a_1\dots a_k)\pi=(\pi(a_1)\dots\pi(a_k))$.

Also, conjugation is a homomorphism.   So, under conjugation, a product of cycles is the product of the conjugates.  To finish, use that any permutation has a representation as a product of disjoint cycles.

Thus there can be no counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you believe you found a counter example because you think that

$(456)(78)$ and $(132)(456)(78)(123)$ are two different cycle types of the same element.

This is not true since $(132)(456)(78)(123)$ is not a product of disjoint cycles.

(Maybe I have misunderstood your misunderstanding)